# Generating the $n^{th}$ full binary tree over $N$ labeled leaves

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs

I am looking for an algorithm to incrementally generate distinct full binary trees over $N$ unique leaves. That is, I want an algorithm that can generate the $n^{th}$ distinct tree without generating all the $n-1$ trees before. Pre-generating all trees is practically impossible above a certain `N`.

A full binary tree with its $N$ leaves labeled is equivalent to a binary grouping of $N$ unique elements grouped into pairs. There are $C_{N-1}$ different full binary trees or groupings of `N` leaves, where $C_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Catalan number. For $N = 4$, there are $C_3 = 5$ trees. These are, with internal nodes labeled $5..7$ and with the equivalent grouping:

[image]

For $N = 5$:

```
(1 (2 (3 (4 5))))
(1 (2 ((3 4) 5)))
(1 ((2 3) (4 5)))
(1 ((2 (3 4)) 5))
(1 (((2 3) 4) 5))
((1 2) (3 (4 5)))
((1 2) ((3 4) 5))
((1 (2 3)) (4 5))
((1 (2 (3 4))) 5)
((1 ((2 3) 4)) 5)
(((1 2) 3) (4 5))
(((1 2) (3 4)) 5)
(((1 (2 3)) 4) 5)
((((1 2) 3) 4) 5)
```

I see three ways to solve this problem (ultimately they are equivalent):

1. There is a simple algorithm that can directly generate the next distinct (non-isomorphic) tree incrementally.
2. There is a bijective encoding from tree $T_i$ to sequence $S_i$ such that generating $S_{i+1}$ (decoding into tree $T_{i+1}$) is easily doable.
3. In the ideal case, there is a simple bijection of the $C_{N-1}$ trees to a continuous interval of $C_{N-1}$ natural numbers (preferentially $(1..C_{N-1})$) so that generating the $i^{th}$ tree is as easy as to decode it from the integer $i$.

There are many algorithms to encode a binary tree to a bijectively unique sequence (e.g. to a Prüfer sequence) but the issue is then how to generate the *next* sequence that can be decoded to the *next* tree without many failed sequences that do not encode a valid tree of the above description and do not encode a tree that was already visited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to fully parenthesize a string of $n$ letters, $C_{n-1}$, obeys the following recurrence:
$$
C_{n-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}C_{i-1}C_{n-i-1}
$$
To see this, consider the two "shallowest" groups in the parenthesization. Namely, ignoring the leftmost `(` and the rightmost `)`, look at the parenthesis matching the leftmost `(`. This will surround the first $i$ letters in the string, which can be further paranthesized in $C_{i-1}$ ways, while the latter $n-i$ letters can be parenthesized in $C_{n-i-1}$ ways. For example when $n=5$, the $*$ illustrates all of the break points:

```
(1 * (2 (3 (4 5)))) C(0) * C(4) strings where the break point
(1 * (2 ((3 4) 5))) is after i=1
(1 * ((2 3) (4 5)))
(1 * ((2 (3 4)) 5))
(1 * (((2 3) 4) 5))

((1 2) * (3 (4 5))) C(1) * C(2) strings where the break point
((1 2) * ((3 4) 5)) is after i=2

((1 (2 3)) * (4 5)) C(2) * C(1) strings where the break point
(((1 2) 3) * (4 5)) is after i=3

((1 (2 (3 4))) * 5) C(4) * C(0) strings where the break point
((1 ((2 3) 4)) * 5) is after i=4
(((1 2) (3 4)) * 5)
(((1 (2 3)) 4) * 5)
((((1 2) 3) 4) * 5)
```

This recurrence gives you a quickly computable bijection from the first $C_{n-1}$ non-negative integers to binary trees. You are given an integer $k$ for which $0\le k\le C_{n-1}-1$. Compute the partial sums
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{s-1} C_{i-1}C_{n-i-1}
$$
to find the largest number $s\ge 1$ for which that partial sum is at most $k$. Then, insert parentheses into the list of numbers `(1 2 3 ... n)` as follows:

```
((1 2 ... s) (s+1 s+2 ... n))
```

If $s=1$, you can omit the parentheses around `(1)`, and similarly when $s=n-1$ around `(n)`.

Then, letting $$e=k - \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}C_{i-1}C_{n-i-1}\Big),$$ and letting \begin{align}k_1&=e\pmod {C_{s-1}}\\k_2&=\lfloor e/C_{s-1}\rfloor,\end{align} you will have $0\le k_1\le C_{s-1}-1$ and $0\le k_2\le C_{n-s-1}-1$, and you can recursively apply the bijections for $k_1$ to the list `(1 2 ... s)` and for $k_2$ to the list `(s+1 s+2 ... n)`.

**Edit:** There was a "bug" in my bijection which I just fixed. You can test that it works [here](https://repl.it/@mearnest/Catalan-Bijection?language=python3&folderId=).

**Edit2:** I just fixed another off-by-one error.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the first part a bit more? Why do you involve multiplication? What do you mean by "last multiplication"? Also, you write:  "then you must first multiply the numbers 1…i in Ci−1 ways". Multiplication is commutative so I can only multiply a list of numbers in exactly one way. Perhaps a noncommutative binary operation would be better to consider here, that respects parenthesis? But then the Catalan decomposition wouldn't make sense in this analogy, am I right?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes, using multiplication as an example was confusing, I should have used a non-associative operation, one where $(a*b)*c\neq a*(b*c)$. I have reworded the explanation, does it make more sense now?

Comment: Thanks Mike, this makes more sense for me now! BTW, your code is marvellously simple and explains better than a thousand words. Could easily port it to my taste. Also, I think [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318972/32412) is relevant.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thank you for the kind words!

Comment: I wonder how one can reverse the algorithm to get the integer $k$ from a given binary grouping. This does not seem trivial. Any idea on this?

Comment: It is not so bad. The $k$ you want to find is given by $$k=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}C_{i-1}C_{n-i-1}\right)+k_1+k_2C_{s-1},$$where $s$ is the number just before the `)` which matches with the `(` just before `1` (exception; if `1` is grouped by itself, then $s=1$), and where $k_1,k_2$ are computed recursively by applying the inverse bijections to the parenthesizations of `1 2 ... s` and `s+1 s+2 ... n`. @IstvánZachar

Comment: Thank you Mike. But wouldn't this lead to infinite recursion? If $s$ is the last number in the innermost grouping starting with `1`, than in case of e.g. `(1 (2 (3 (4 5))))`, $s$ is `5` and $k_1$ is infinitely calculated for `(1 (2 (3 (4 5))))` while the rest (`s+1 s+2 ... n`) is empty.

Comment: @IstvánZachar in you example $s=1$. This was the exception I mentioned; 1 is grouped with itself. The idea is that $s$ occurs just before the break between the “shallowest” groups. Refer back to the second paragraph of original post, and the following example. The first five groupings in that code block all have $s=1$.

Comment: Ok, with this last bit I managed to wrap my head around the problem. Thanks again for your continued help!