# Given a binary tree with N labelled leaves, is it possible to find its unique number in the Catalan range?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, planar-graphs, catalan-numbers

The question is about finding the inverse to the problem of generating the $n^{th}$ binary tree with N labelled leaves ([Generating the $n^{th}$ full binary tree over $N$ labelled leaves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101560/generating-the-nth-full-binary-tree-over-n-labeled-leaves)).

Let's say if $N = 4$, the possible set of trees are

```
1: (((1, 2), 3), 4)
2: (1, ((2, 3), 4))
3: ((1, (2, 3)), 4)
4: (1, (2, (3, 4)))
5: ((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

If I choose a specific tree from this set, let's say $(1, ((2, 3), 4))$, is there an algorithm that gives me back the value 2? The Catalan range for the problem is 1 to 5 and the unique number corresponding to the given tree is 2.

**What do I mean by Catalan Range?**

If there are N leaf nodes, the maximum possible binary trees is $C(N-1)$. For a given $n$, its $C(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ Catalan number. We can uniquely identify all the individual binary trees if we assign them a number from $1$ to $C(N-1)$ in order. I'm referring to this range of numbers from $1$ to $C(N-1)$ as the **Catalan Range**.

**What scheme am I using to order the trees from $1$ to $C(N-1)$?**

I don't really mind the scheme used to order the trees as long as all the trees can be uniquely identified within that scheme. For example,

*$1$: The tree having just one node in the left sub tree and $N-1$ nodes in the right sub tree.* 
*$2$: The tree still having just one node in the left sub tree and with a slightly different right sub tree now.* 
. 
. 
*$C(N-1)$: The tree having $N-1$ nodes in the left sub tree and one node in the right sub tree.*

For the sake of making it easier to discuss the answer, we could follow the scheme as decided by the first answer in this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101560/generating-the-nth-full-binary-tree-over-n-labeled-leaves).

Comment: Could you give a reference to what you call the "Catalan space" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have explained it in the description, I'll give it another shot here. If there are N nodes, the maximum possible binary trees is C(N). C(N) is the Nth Catalan number. We can uniquely identify all the individual binary trees if we assign them a number from 1 to C(N) in order. I'm referring to this range of numbers from 1 to C(N) as the "Catalan Space".

Comment: Which order are you using to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes, that's a good question. I don't really mind the scheme used to order the trees as long as they can be uniquely identified within that scheme. For example, I could start by assigning 1 to the tree having just one node in the left sub tree and N-1 nodes in the right sub tree. 2 can be assigned to the tree with two nodes in the left sub tree and N-2 nodes in the right and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have been misled by the word "space" which tends to refer to an underlying structure (algebraic, geometric, topological...). IMHO, "Catalan range" would be a more adapted word.

Comment: @JeanMarie, no problem. Yeah, now that I think about it, "range" makes more sense. :)

Comment: Also, I made a mistake while typing the description. For given N leaf nodes, there are C(N-1) possible binary trees and not C(N) trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be the function mapping full binary trees to integers; I'll use the convention that binary trees with $n$ leaves will map to the range $\{0, 1, \dots, C_{n-1}-1\}$ because that's easier to work with in the recursion. You can add $1$ later.

If we have a binary tree $T$, let $L$ be the "left" subtree: the subtree with leaves $1, 2, \dots, k$ for some $k$. Let $R$ be the "right" subtree: the subtree with leaves $k+1, k+2, \dots, n$. We will find $f(T)$ in terms of $f(L)$, $f(R)$, and $k$ where for the purposes of finding $f(R)$ we relabel $R$ to have leave $1, 2, \dots, n-k$.

Our trees are labeled in increasing order of $k$. So before this tree, we have
$$
   C_0 C_{n-2} + C_1 C_{n-3} + \dots + C_{k-2} C_{n-k} 
$$
trees whose left subtree has $1, 2, \dots, k-1$ leaves respectively.

Next, before this particular left subtree $L$, there are $f(L)$ previous left subtrees on $k$ leaves; for each one of them, there are $C_{n-k-1}$ right subtrees. All $f(L) C_{n-k-1}$ of the combined $n$-leaf trees go before $T$.

Finally, there are $f(R)$ trees with the same left subtree, but with a right subtree preceding $R$; these also go before $T$.

Altogether, we get the recursion
$$
    f(T) = \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} C_{i-1} C_{n-i-1} + f(L) C_{n-k-1} + f(R).
$$
The base of the recursion sets $f(T) = 0$ when $T$ has just one or two leaves, in which case there's only one possible tree. (Actually, we only need the one-leaf case as our base case.)

Comment: For this technique to work, we need to know the number of leaf nodes in the left subtree and right subtree upfront?

Comment: Yes, because that's the primary thing determining the order in which we're listing the subtrees - at least if use the enumeration method in the answer you cited. All the trees with one leaf in $L$ go before all the trees with two leaves in $L$, which go before all the trees with three leaves in $L$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I implemented it in a Python program and it works perfectly! :)